# Как сделать веб приложение на Django?

Tags: python, django, html5, веб-программирование, pyqt

Вопрос странный, но можете новичку объяснить как правильно делать веб приложение на Django? Я создал проект Django, примерно разобрался где какие файлы настраивать, а как собственно делать страницу? Во всех видеоуроках люди сами вручную прописывают html код и вставляют css стили из разных шаблонов bootstrap. А как это делать по-человечески? Когда ты пишешь десктопное приложение например на PyQt или WPF(Windows Forms) у тебя есть редактор интерфейса, где ты можешь перетаскивать кнопочки, таблицы, формы и т.п. и потом уже их связывать с кодом на бекенде. А как это в Django сделать? Есть ли какой то адекватный редактор веб интерфейса. Извиняюсь если вопрос совсем глупый, но я только разбираюсь в этой теме.

P.S. Я хочу сделать одностраничное веб приложение, где будет два TextInput, одна кнопка и карта (google или yandex), куда вводишь город, срабатывает другой python скрипт, который выдает координаты города и он отображается на карте. Как это лучше сделать?

Comment: Чем хороша Django - все изменения вносимые в код видно без перезагрузки сайта. И устанавливается очень быстро и просто - проще среди cms не встречал еще. Из главных недостатков - трудность работы с базами данными. В Django реализован свой собственный подход к организации БД и только из-за этого пришлось отказаться от ее использования.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пробовали смотреть ютуб ? Как по мне там есть годные гайды.
Например https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w4nrT7emiVc&t=1484s
Или вот https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6K83dgjkQNw
Ну или поищите что вам более интересно https://www.youtube.com/resultssearch_query=django%20%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B8
UPD:
Дочитал ваш пост, да все учат html,css,js... ибо писать сайт и не знать чем отличается блочная вёрстка от табличной или id от класса это плоховато, можно например делать страницу на тильде или виксе и потом копировать код страницы но... сайты от этого защищены так-что с первого раза может не выйти. А из софта знаю пару программ, но вспомнил только Adobe Muse. Так что как-то так =)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Да, я конечно посмотрел много уроков по самому Django, но до меня так и не дошло как правильно разметку делать, ну невозможно же весь html код вручную писать. Мы же когда декстопное приложение делаем, мы разметку не пишем там руками, есть куча редакторов интерфейса. А как с веб приложениями обстоит дела вот разбираюсь. Adobe Muse сейчас попробую, звучит как хорошая идея, но какая то непопулярная вроде. Как же правильно это организовать?

Comment: @RoyalGoose к сожалению в веб разметка делается вручную тут нету QT редактора. Приложения типа Adobe Muse из ряда вон выходящего. Безусловно есть редакторы типа Tilda или Wix, но вы слышали чтоб хорошие проекты делали на них ?
В основном все в веб пишется с нуля! Есть готовые стили по типу bootstrap и ему подобных, НО даже bootstrap4 нужен больше для примерки дизайна то есть дизайн на нем делается за пару дней, но почти не кто так не оставляет. Есть более легкие фреймворки по типу bootstrap, но это как по мне максимум что может упростить веб разработку. А так все ручками) проще и надежнее.

Comment: @RoyalGoose Кроме Adobe Muse вспомнил также Adobe Dreamweaver, но опять же они не блещят популярностью

Comment: хорошо, спасибо за комментарий. Отмечу ваш ответ как правильный, и буду учить веб верстку с нуля :)